# WCF Application "Unable to find assembly" for SQLite

Tags: wcf, iis, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Note: This is a solved problem, but I just spend 4 hours at this issue, so I wanted to share the solution.

---

When I attempt to access a WCF service, the service never responds, and the event log shows the following:

> An unhandled exception occurred and
>   the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: DefaultDomain
>
> Process ID: 3180
>
> Exception:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>
> Message: Unable to find assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'.
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
>   assemblyInfo, String name)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
>   objectName, String[] memberNames,
>   BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
>   Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[]
>   memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
>   objectReader, Int32 objectId,
>   BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
>   SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary._*BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
>   record)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum
>   binaryHeaderEnum)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser,
>   Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler
>   handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream
>   stm)    at
>   System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[]
>   blob)    at
>   System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[]
>   blob)

---

**Solution**
In my case, the problem ended up being a simple incorrect database path.  However, the error message in no way reflects the actual cause, so YMMV.

The reason the "bad connection string" exception didn't make it to the event log seems related to [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911816).  If the connection string isn't your problem, then your best course may be to follow the steps in this article, which will cause IIS to write exceptions to the event log.